# How to create database view in coredata

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I have quite a few fields in an entity in core data (say the entity is called Address) such as street, number, city, and state. I want the user to input a text string such that the app will search the entity Address for records which matches. How should I do this?

I basically want to have a generated field (search field) which will be "number, street, city, state" and try to find a record such that this search field contains the input string. I want this field to automatically updates itself when any field it contains (e.g., "number", "street", "city", "state") changes.

I was looking around on Google and found the database view thing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) which seems promising. But I cannot find any information on how to create a database view in core data. Anybody can point me a direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a computed property in your Address class and use it for your search. It will update if you change any of the attributes it uses.

```
var fullAddress: String {
    return "\(number) \(street) \(city ?? "") \(state ?? "")"
}
```

(Here I assumed city and state are optional attributes)

Regarding a Db view, Core Data is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and not a SQL database so there is no such thing as a view.

Comment: This works. Basically this will fetch all records to the memory and then filter them, am I right?

Comment: This property will exist for each instance (record) that is loaded into memory and you can search it inside a loop for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand some parts of your questions, but my initial thoughts:

> I have quite a few fields in an entity in core data (say the entity is
>   called Address) such as street, number, city, and state. I want the
>   user to input a text string such that the app will search the entity
>   Address for records which matches. How should I do this?
>
> I basically want to have a generated field (search field) which will
>   be "number, street, city, state" and try to find a record such that
>   this search field contains the input string. I want this field to
>   automatically updates itself when any field it contains (e.g.,
>   "number", "street", "city", "state") changes.

Assign your controller (or another object) as a delegate to the UITextField. Override the most appropriate delegate method and then perform a fetch query on the Core Data model with the entered string. Update your view in the callback with the top most result.

> I was looking around on Google and found the SQL view thing which
>   seems promising. But I cannot find any information on how to create a
>   database view in core data. Anybody can point me a direction? Thanks!

A SQL View? Are you talking about a database browser? DB Browser Lite has always done the job for me - it allows you to browse the schema, the data and perform SQL queries. Print out to the console the location of the model, and then use the OS File Browser to navigate to that location.

In Objective-C, that console print out would look something like:

```
     - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
        return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    }
```

Xcode doesn't have a DB viewer per say. As you probably know, you can easily edit the entities and their attritibutes in the Table View when you have the .xccdatamodelId file selected. From that file, you can inspect the entire model and its relationships in the Graph View, almost like a UML snapshot.

Comment: I do not know how to query the coredata if the schema for the Address table contains multiple columns like "street", "Country", "Province", given the user just make one input string and type in whatever the user wants. This is the database view I am referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)

Comment: something like:NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Location"];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"street == %@ OR country == %@", value, value]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *locations = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Comment: The user can input two fields in the string as well... But this is definitely one way to do it.